# Using gradient effect in sprite kit decrease fps from 60 to 30

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, gradient

I am working on a sprite kit game project for ios, and my game runs on 60 fps without using Gradient Effect. What I am using is `self.backgroundcolor = [SkColor randomColor]`, but when I use Gradient effect on my background, my game straight goes down to 30 fps.

Below is my code that I am using for Gradient effect.

This method is in my SkScene class not in my ViewController class.

```
#pragme mark - Gradient Effect setup.

- (void)drawRect
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1168, 660));       //For landscape mode.
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


CGGradientRef gradient;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

CGFloat location[] = {1};

UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:(48/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.0];
UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0)  green:(251/255.0)  blue:(255/255.0)  alpha:1.0];

NSArray *color = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorTwo.CGColor,
                  (id)colorOne.CGColor, nil];

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef) color, location);

CGPoint startPoint, endPoint;
startPoint.x = 0;
startPoint.y = 0;

endPoint.x = 0;
endPoint.y = 250;

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);

UIImage *newimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
SKTexture *newte = [SKTexture textureWithImage:newimage];
newte.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKSpriteNode *newnode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:newte];
newnode.zPosition = -10;


[gradientCloud addChild:newnode];


}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What device? If you're testing on Simulator, ignore it, test on a device.

Comment: I am testing it on a Simulator, does it make any difference.

Comment: Yup, like about one or two worlds of a difference. Simulator rendering performance is terrible, on the other hand it can use your Mac's CPU and memory which is plenty more than on a device. When it comes to performance only devices count.

Comment: Do you have that method in the SKScene or in the SKView? I'm asking because drawRect is a method inherited from UIVIew... and maybe you are executing that code a lot of times, dropping your performance. 
You just need to set the background with `self.backgroundcolor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newimage]`in the same place you are setting the random color...

Comment: I've already tried this `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newimage];` but it change the color to black. And my Gradient effect code is in my SkScene class.

Comment: I had the same issue with just rendering a full screen background images so its not just the gradient effect. As LearnCocos2D already mentioned test performance only on a device.

Comment: How much is the difference if i test it on device.

Comment: Does `drawRect` called once or it called during every drawing cycle?
Can you log drawRect calls?

Comment: It calls every time when i enter and exit from my game class. And i implemented gradient in the same game class. Around 2 - 3 time calls.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem where I used a large sprite with an image as a background for one of my scenes.  Without it, (just self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor]), the fps was around 60, but the moment I added a background, it dropped to around 30.

The problem was that I was testing the app on the simulator.  When I loaded the app to a real device, the fps went back up to 60.  I even added some particle effects to the scene too and the fps still was 60.  Test out your project on a real device to see if the fps drops.  If it does, then there's another problem.  if not, you're all good!

Comment: I ran into the same issue. The FPS was fine on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

The frames per second is based on how fast the device can process your draw rect method. Move EVERYTHING that is static outside of it and try again. For example:

```
UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:(48/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.0];
UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0)  green:(251/255.0)  blue:(255/255.0)  alpha:1.0];

NSArray *color = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorTwo.CGColor,
                  (id)colorOne.CGColor, nil];
```

Never changes, move it outside and make color a class variable.

Also the gradient itself seems to be static, move it outside as well. The draw rect is meant to be for things that should be recalculated at every cycle.

**EDIT:**

I just read your code once again, i am uncertain what you are trying to achieve. But most of it seems to be static. Move it outside of the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice would be to test on an actual device, and maybe even actually create a gradient image for the node in Illustrator or Gimp (free) or whatever you can use.

Comment: Using gradient image causing same problem.